# get values of nested query in mysql

Tags: mysql, nested

```
SELECT *, count(idWallHasWallPost) as republish FROM admin_pw.wall_has_wallpost 
    where WallPost_idWallPost in 
    (select WallPost_idWallPost from wall_has_wallpost where Wall_idWall in 
    (select Wall_idWall from follower where User_idUser=1))
    group by WallPost_idWallPost 
    having republish>1;
```

I have this nested query in mysql. Is there anyway to acces the values from the nested queries higher up in the query.

I would like to access Wall_idWall in last select. I select it the query lowest and would like to see which Wall_idWall was used by the in operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT w.*, count(w.idWallHasWallPost) as republish, v.all_Wall_idWall
FROM admin_pw.wall_has_wallpost w
join (select h.WallPost_idWallPost, 
             group_concat(distinct h.Wall_idWall) all_Wall_idWall
      from wall_has_wallpost h
      join follower f on h.Wall_idWall = f.Wall_idWall and f.User_idUser=1
      group by h.WallPost_idWallPost) v
on w.WallPost_idWallPost = v.WallPost_idWallPost
group by WallPost_idWallPost 
having republish>1;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this if you only need Wall_idWall in last select

```
SELECT *, count(idWallHasWallPost) as republish,(select Wall_idWall from follower where User_idUser=1) as Wall_idWall FROM admin_pw.wall_has_wallpost 
where WallPost_idWallPost in 
(select WallPost_idWallPost from wall_has_wallpost where Wall_idWall in 
(select Wall_idWall from follower where User_idUser=1))
group by WallPost_idWallPost 
having republish>1;
```

OR you can change where clause according to your requirements.